# for-loop does not work for a model list in Spring MVC

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, spring-mvc, el

I am developing an application with Spring MVC. In my form I would like the city name-field to be automatically  filled in when a zip code is inserted by the user. I therefore parsed a .csv file to objects `ZipCity` (for each zip code an object) and created and array list `zipCityListCh` with those object. I tried to loop through the list on the .jsp page using JavaScript (in order to match the zip code), but the iteration does not work.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  var zip = document.getElementById("field-zipCode");
  zip.addEventListener("blur", zipToCity, false);

  function zipToCity() {
    var field = document.getElementById("field-city");
 
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      if ("${zipCityAsArray[i].zip==zip.value}") {
        field.value = "${zipCityAsArray[i].city}";
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
</script>
```

It DOES work, though, if I insert a number instead of the variable `i`:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  var zip = document.getElementById("field-zipCode");
  zip.addEventListener("blur", zipToCity, false);

  function zipToCity() {
    var field = document.getElementById("field-city");
 
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      if ("${zipCityAsArray[1].zip==zip.value}") {
        field.value = "${zipCityAsArray[1].city}";
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
</script>
```

It seems as though the variable `i` is not recognized as a number. Here's the controller code:

```js
private ZipCityList zipCityListCh = new ZipCityList("src/main/resources/files/plz.csv");
private ArrayList<ZipCity> zipCityAsArray = zipCityListCh.getZipCityAsArrayList();
 
@RequestMapping(value = "/createAd", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView createAd(){
  ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("create-ad");  
  model.addObject("zipCityAsArray",zipCityAsArray );
  model.addObject("adForm", new AdForm());

  return model;
}
```

Why isn't the first snippet working?

Comment: You are mixing server and client side eval. Your `zipCityAsArray` is bound in the controller before `var i` is visible on the client side. But the server side view is where your bound model attributes are evaluated - and there i isn't visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Dirk Lachowski said in his comment: since EL is server side code and gets compiled into a Java class first, before it's run on server, there's no variable `i` defined in its scope. JavaScript on the other hand runs on client side and is run much later, when the EL has already been evaluated. You can check the page source to see what's returned by the server after browser loads the page and what's the amount of data available when your JavaScript runs its loop.

If you really want to use JavaScript to make the loop with the data of a server side variable, then you can populate it into a JavaScript data structure with JSTL tags or fetch it from the server with an AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for the explanations! I tried then different ways and eventually solved it by embedding HTML forEach inside the javascript function... It is working great!

```js
function zipToCity() {
  var field = document.getElementById("field-city");

  <c:forEach items="${zipCityAsArray}" var="item">
  var zipFromObj = parseInt("${item.zip}");

  var rooms = document.getElementById("field-nrOfRooms");
  rooms.value = zipFromObj;

  if (zipFromObj == zip.value) {
   field.value = "${item.city}";
  }
  </c:forEach>
        
        return true;

     }
```